# Changing Specific attribute

Tags: regex, xml, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, findinfiles

I want to change a specific attribute in the each file (there are total 350 of them) with same code.

For example, Folder 'Target' there are 350 files that have same attribute that I would like to change.
in file A,

```
     <revised-comment MCR="">REVISED EFFECT TEXT A to 13</revised-comment>
```

in file B,

```
    <revised-comment MCR="">REVISED EFFECT TEXT B to 14</revised-comment>
```

in file C,

```
    <revised-comment MCR="">REVISED EFFECT TEXT C to 15</revised-comment>
```

I have 350 files have same manner of attribute, only their values are slightly different. Here, I would like to use a "find in file" in the Sublime Text to find all of revised-comment attributes to change with this.

```
    <revised-comment MCR=""></revised-comment>
```

Is there any way I can do with regex syntax to do this with? Your help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should only require a simple pattern mostly consisting of literal characters.

Find: `<revised-comment MCR="">.+</revised-comment>`

Replace `<revised-comment MCR=""></revised-comment>`

The only actual "regex" part of this is the `.+` to match the variable inner text. The `.` symbol matches any character other than newline and carriage return, and the `+` symbol signifies that it should match `.` one or more times.